# Devise - Login only after multiple attempts - Subdomains and PG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, devise, subdomain

I'm using `rails 3.2` and `devise 3.0`

I'm using subdomains and PG's multiple schemas to segregate one account from another .

Users on my system are able to login only after multiple attempts. There is nothing in the log and I'm absolutely clueless. I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

My code is as follows:

Application Controller -

```
before_filter :setup_schema

def setup_schema
  if request.subdomain.blank? || request.subdomain == 'www'
    redirect_to "http://www.#{ENV['DOMAIN']}.com"
  else
    @tenant = Account.find_by_name(request.subdomain)
    if @tenant.nil?
      redirect_to "http://www.#{ENV['DOMAIN']}.com"
    else
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_search_path = "#{@tenant.schema},hstore"
      Delayed::Job.table_name = 'public.delayed_jobs'
    end
  end
end
```

Session Store -

```
XXX::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_XXX_session', domain: :all
```

routes:

```
 devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: "registrations"}, path_names: { sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"} 
as :user do
    get 'users/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', as: 'edit_user_registration'
    get 'users/edit_password' => 'devise/registrations#edit_password', as: 'edit_pass_user_registration'
    post "user_create" => "users#create",  as: 'user_create'
end

resources :dashboards, only: [:index]

devise_scope :user do
  constraints(Subdomain) do
    authenticated :user do
      root to: 'dashboards#index'
    end
    unauthenticated :user do
      root to: 'sessions#new'
    end
    root to: 'dashboards#index'
  end
end
```

Another issue that I'm facing is -

Lets say I'm logged in 1 subdomain and I'm at root path, ie, `subdomain1.XXX.com` and then I login with another user in another subdomain in another browser, now when I come to my first subdomain, I get logged out.
However, if I was a some other url eg, `subdomain1.XXX.com/projects` and then I login with another user in another subdomain in another browser, now when I come to my first subdomain, I DONT get logged out.

Can some point what is it that I'm missing?
I'm missing some key concept or this has to with devise?

Edit to add log -

```
Started POST "/users/login" 
Completed 302 Found in 197.2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"F/QNpMOAxEHK1Y/M9n1vyyqqPvO0859XNqd4ylrI+G0=", "user"=>{"login"=>"login1", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Entrar"}
Redirected to http://subdomain2.XXX.com/

heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users/login"     host=subdomain2.XXX.com 
Started GET "/" 
Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.haml (1.4ms)
Rendered layouts/_messages.html.haml (0.1ms)

Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/login (10.7ms)
```

heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=subdomain2.XXX.com

Comment: There must me something in the log so it would be great if you could include the log of unsuccessful vs successful login attempt.

Comment: As to your second question: you're sharing one session in Rails between the subdomains so it's natural that when you log into another account first session is invalidated. You should probably scope session cookies to the subdomain.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel I have edited question to add log